# display mysql query result from array parameters php

Tags: php, mysql

I'll do my best to explain i create a query to return rows for a search function ex : return row WHERE id LIKE  = *_*_

here's my code :

```
if(!empty($champs)){
$table[0]["prog"] = array('mydb.message','Message'); 

$table[1]["prog"]  = array('mydb.newtable','Username','nom','prenom');
```

as the table and columns to look into

```
            $nb_result =0;


            for($i =0 ; $i < count ($table); $i++)
            {                       
                $prog_tab = $table[$i]["prog"];         


                             $sql = sprintf("SELECT * 
                                            FROM %s 
                                            WHERE 1 ",
                                $prog_tab [0], 
                                DEFAULT_ACCESS_LEVEL);  

                for($j = 1; $j < count ($prog_tab ); $j++)
                {
                        $sql .= sprintf(" OR %s LIKE '%s' ",
                                $prog_tab [$j],

                                $this->ins_string("%".$champs."%"), 
                                DEFAULT_ACCESS_LEVEL);
                }   
                echo $sql;
                        /*$sql =  $table[$i]["user"][0]  . ' ---> ' . $sql."<br>"; */
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                if($table[$i]["prog"][1] == "Message"){
                    echo $rows['Sender']." : &nbsp".$rows['Message']."<br />";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo $rows['Username']."&nbsp".$rows['nom']."&nbsp".$rows['prenom']."<br />";
                    }
                }
            $nb_result += mysql_num_rows($query);

            }           


        echo "<br /><h1>".$nb_result."</h1>";
        }
```

the problem is when i display the query it returns all the rows from my 2 tables and just ignore the LIKE %$champs%

NOTE* when i display the query it seems fine : `SELECT * 
                                                FROM mydb.newtable 
                                                WHERE 1  OR Username LIKE '%$champs%'  OR nom LIKE '%$champs%'  OR prenom LIKE '%$champs%'`
and $nb_result always returns 48 (amount of rows i have in the two tables combined )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `where` clause basically boils down a boolean decision for the database, "include this row, or don't include it". Since you're doing

```
SELECT ... WHERE 1 OR ... OR ... OR ...
                 ^--
```

you're ALWAYS producing a 'true' value, so all rows will match and be included.

Remember your boolean truth tables. `true OR anything` is true.

Comment: thank you very much!! i feel a bit stupid now ahah i forgot that 1 is for the AND